# JBOSS 7.1 IBM MQ Configuration with INITIAL CONTEXT

Tags: java, jboss7.x, ibm-mq

Here is my resource-adapter, but I have to go by initial context set up without using this resource-adapter. Find my initial context set up below:

```
<resource-adapter>
    <archive>
        wmq.jmsra.rar
    </archive>
    <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
    <connection-definitions>
        <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/CONFACTORY1" pool-name="CONFACTORY1">
            <config-property name="port">
                1234
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="hostName">
                172.16.70.2
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="channel">
                SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="transportType">
                CLIENT
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="queueManager">
                QUEUEMGR
            </config-property>
        </connection-definition>
    </connection-definitions>
    <admin-objects>
        <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/JMSQUEUE" pool-name="MQ.QUEUE.NAME">
            <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                JMSQUEUE
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                QUEUEMGR
            </config-property>
        </admin-object>
    </admin-objects>
</resource-adapter>

final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://172.16.70.2:1234");

//   env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
//   env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "sn@12345");
InitialContext   context = new InitialContext(env);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up IBM MQ components via JNDI from a remote client (another JVM), is not supported by the IBM MQ JCA.  The IBM connection factories and destinations can only be accessed from the JVM that loads the IBM MQ JCA.

Comment: The IBM MQ JCA provides access to MQ, either locally or remotely, to the JVM that loads the IBM MQ JCA.  This JVM should not export IBM MQ connection factories and destinations via JNDI.